# Deleting empty meta key values

Tags: database, sql

Is it safe to use

```sql
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE `meta_value` = ''
```

in SQL in order to remove meta keys with empty values? Could any errors or problems occur?

Comment: It depends on the value and how/whether it's used by whatever added it to begin with.

Comment: @Jacob Peattie I am talking about empty meta values. Any meta key that has an empty value.

Comment: As I said: It depends on the value and how/whether it's used by whatever added it to begin with. There's no blanket answer.

Comment: But the value is always empty...how can it depend on the value? My question is bevause I want to clean up the wp_postmeta.

Comment: Because it depends on whether the whatever theme/plugin added it expects it to exist or not, even if it's empty.